# Remove button in CKEditor Angular 4

Tags: angular, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I'm using the basic version `4.7.3/basic/ckeditor.js` and wondering how to remove "About" and "NumberedList" buttons.

Any idea how do I do this?

```
<ckeditor
  [(ngModel)]="work.points"
  [config]="{removePlugins: 'About'}">
</ckeditor>
```

This doesn't work. I tried with `removeButtons: 'About'` as well but that seems to add more buttons instead of removing the About button!

Answer (score 0):

You edit the config.js and do:

```
config.removePlugins = 'about';
config.removeButtons = 'About';
```

You can also just do your own toolbar and not add the 'About' button.

Comment: Is there any way to do it as an attribute of the <ckeditor> tag, instead of manually achieving this via config.js